# create a list subsetting data frame and join other list based on previous in r

Tags: r, list

I have ***time series*** for each ***product***:

```
ts <- list()
ts[["p1"]] <- ts(seq(1,5), start=c(2019,1), frequency=12)
ts[["p2"]] <- ts(seq(1,5), start=c(2019,1), frequency=12)
ts[["p3"]] <- ts(seq(1,5), start=c(2019,1), frequency=12)
ts[["p4"]] <- ts(seq(1,5), start=c(2019,1), frequency=12)
ts[["p5"]] <- ts(seq(1,5), start=c(2019,1), frequency=12)
```

and a relationship between ***product*** and ***category*** in a data frame

```
category <- c("cA","cA","cB","cB","cB")
product <- c("p1","p2","p3","p4","p5")
df_product_category <- data.frame(product,category)
```

I first want a ***list*** for each ***category***:

```
list_category <- list(unique(df_product_category$category))
#this doesn´t work
```

Then I want to create another ***list*** per ***category*** containing all the ***products*** within the category

```
list_category <- c("cA","cB")
```

once I have this list I need a nested list for each category containing each of the ***products*** within that ***category***

```
list_product_category <- list()
list_product_category$'cA' <- c("p1","p2")
list_product_category$'cB' <- c("p2","p3","p4")
```

then I wish to create another list ***nesting***: ***category-product-tslike*** this:

```
ts_list_product_category <- list()
ts_list_product_category[[cA]]$p1 <- ts[["p1"]]
ts_list_product_category[[cA]]$p2 <- ts[["p2"]]
ts_list_product_category[[cB]]$p3 <- ts[["p3"]]
ts_list_product_category[[cB]]$p4 <- ts[["p4"]]
ts_list_product_category[[cB]]$p5 <- ts[["p5"]]
```

Thanks in advance :)

Comment: Do you mean `split(df_product_category, df_product_category$category)` ?

Comment: Do you need `split(df_product_category$product, df_product_category$category)`, If not please edit your post to show expected output.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can do a `split` to create the 'list_product_category'.  Once we have that it is easier to create the 'ts_list_product_category', by just subsetting using the values as names for the 'ts'

```
list_product_category <- with(df_product_category,    
          split(as.character(product), category))

out <-  lapply(list_product_category, function(x) ts[x])
```

-checking with OP's created output

```
identical(out, ts_list_product_category )
#[1] TRUE
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this... A robust approach.

```
library(tidyverse)

(d <- df_product_category %>% group_by(category) %>% nest()) %>% glimpse()
```

**output dataset structure**

```
Observations: 2
Variables: 2
Groups: category [2]
$ category <fct> cA, cB
$ data     <list> [<tbl_df[2 x 1]>, <tbl_df[3 x 1]>]
```

Comment: thanks, but I would need a list as output like:  - f$'cA' -  which gives me the a list with 2 elements: 'p1' , 'p2'